# C program immediatley exits after execution, yet it has a while(1) loop

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, linker

I'm trying to fit a minesweeper program in c under a 3KB limit so it can fit in a qr code, and it was working fine until when I added the option `-nostdlib` and compiled it, the program immediately exited, despite having a while(1) loop in main with no way of exiting.

The libraries I added in linker were `kernel32`, `gcc`, and `msvcrt` (in case you want to re-produce it). And while it did technically return 0x0, which means it was 'successful', it obviously wasn't; or it wouldn't have done that. My code can be seen here:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 100
#define BOMBS 801

int xorshf96(int x, int y, int z)
{
   unsigned long t;
   x ^= x << 16;
   x ^= x >> 5;
   x ^= x << 1;

   t = x;
   x = y;
   y = z;
   z = t ^ x ^ y;

  return z;
}


void ExpandGrid(int fullGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int blankPos[2])
{
    int neighbors[8][2] = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},
                          {0,-1},        {-1,0},
                          {-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,-1}};
    int curTile[2];

    knownGrid[blankPos[0]][blankPos[1]] = 1;
    if(fullGrid[blankPos[0]][blankPos[1]] != 0) return;

    for(int blck = 0; blck < 8; ++blck)
    {
        curTile[0] = abs(blankPos[0]+neighbors[blck][0]);
        curTile[1] = abs(blankPos[1]+neighbors[blck][1]);
        if(curTile[0] > WIDTH-1 || curTile[1] > HEIGHT-1) continue;

        if(fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] == 0 && knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] == 0)
        {
            knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] = 1;
            ExpandGrid(fullGrid, knownGrid, curTile);
        }
        else if(fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] > 0) knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] = 1;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    COORD characterBufferSize = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    COORD characterPosition = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT consoleWriteArea = { 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 };
    CHAR_INFO consoleBuffer[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    HANDLE wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    int num1, num2, num3 = 0;
    SYSTEMTIME systime;

    DWORD numEventsRead = 0;
    DWORD numEvents = 0;
    INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer;
    int wait = 0;

    SetConsoleTitle("Minesweeper!");

    int startGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    int arrowPos[2] = {0, 0};
    int bomb[2] = {0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < BOMBS; i++)
    {
        while (startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] < -1 || bomb[0] <= 0 || bomb[1] <= 0 || bomb[0] >= WIDTH-1 || bomb[1] >= HEIGHT-1)
        {
            GetLocalTime(&systime);
            num1, num2, num3 = (int) systime.wMilliseconds;

            bomb[1] = (xorshf96(num3, num2, num1) % (HEIGHT-1)) + 1;

            GetSystemTime(&systime);
            num1, num2, num3 = (int) systime.wMilliseconds;

            bomb[0] = (xorshf96(num1, num2, num3) % (WIDTH-1)) + 1;
        }

        startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] = -9;

        startGrid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1]]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1]]++;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if (arrowPos[0] > WIDTH-1) arrowPos[0] = WIDTH-1;
        if (arrowPos[0] < 0) arrowPos[0] = 0;
        if (arrowPos[1] > HEIGHT-1) arrowPos[1] = HEIGHT-1;
        if (arrowPos[1] < 0) arrowPos[1] = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
            {

                if (knownGrid[x][y] == 1)
                {
                    if (startGrid[x][y] > 0)
                    {
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = '0' + startGrid[x][y];
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 'o';
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = (startGrid[x][y] < 0 ? FOREGROUND_RED : FOREGROUND_BLUE) | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 00;
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
                }

                if(arrowPos[0] == x && arrowPos[1] == y)
                {
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
                }
            }
        }

        WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, *consoleBuffer, characterBufferSize, characterPosition, &consoleWriteArea);

        numEvents = 0;
        numEventsRead = 0;
        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(rHnd, &numEvents);

        if (numEvents)
        {
            eventBuffer = malloc(sizeof(INPUT_RECORD) * numEvents);
            ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
        }

        if(numEventsRead && wait <= 0)
        {
            wait = 50;
            switch (eventBuffer[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
            {
                case VK_UP:
                    arrowPos[0]--;
                    break;
                case VK_DOWN:
                    arrowPos[0]++;
                    break;
                case VK_LEFT:
                    arrowPos[1]--;
                    break;
                case VK_RIGHT:
                    arrowPos[1]++;
                    break;
                case VK_RETURN:
                    ExpandGrid(startGrid, knownGrid, arrowPos);
                    break;
            }
        }

        wait--;
    }

}
```

Comment: `-nostdlib` ditches the standard libraries *and* the startup functions, from memory. While adding `libgcc` may fix the former, I can't see where you've tried to fix the latter. There's usually a lot of stuff that happens before `main` is called.

Comment: @paxdiablo how can i fix for this? Since I need my program needs to be very small, it was either `-nostdlib` or `-nodefaultlibs`, and removing the default libs seemed to cause more problems.

Comment: I think it may be possible to manually link the cr* objects after `-nostdlib`.

Comment: @SuraajKS what are cr* objects? and how do I link them?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0 ... Have a look at this.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/hello-from-a-libc-free-world-part-1-v2 This is also a good read

Comment: Please show your **full unedited** compilation and link commands. Can you build a working hello world program? If not, your C code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Use of the `-nostdlib` has *two* effects:

- it stops the standard library stuff from being automatically linked; and
- it stops the C runtime start-up code `crt0` from being linked.

That last one is important, there's normally a lot of stuff that happens before `main()` is called and, if you don't link `crt0` then the *real* entry point `_start` (not `main`) does not exist.

So the solution is to provide your *own* `_start` but without all of the messy C environment set-up that's needed for real C programs. That's as simple as providing a `mystart.S` as follows:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    call main           # call main without any setup.
    movl %eax, %ebx     # copy return value to pass back.
    movl $1, %eax       # function code for exit.
    int $0x80           # invoke function.
```

Combine that with a *very* basic C program as follows:

```
int main(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

Then you can compile and test it, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> gcc -nostdlib -o nolibc nolibc.c mystart.S
pax> ./nolibc ; echo $?
42
```

---

That answers your *specific* question, "Why won't it run?". However, I still ended up with a rather chunky executable size, even *with* some extra optimisations gathered from elsewhere:

```
gcc -nostdlib -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -o nolibc nolibc.c mystart.S
strip -s -R .comment -R .gnu.version --strip-unneeded nolibc
```

So, beyond that, you'll probably have to fiddle with the linker script to have it only load what is absolutely necessary for your executable to run.

I won't go into that here since it's a rather large subject and not relevant to your specific question. I'd suggest asking (after searching of course) a different question on how to do that.

---

And keep in mind that `int $80` is a Linux think, from memory. If you want to do something similar for Windows, you should examine how the `crt0` code works on that platform. It's likely to use `ExitProcess()` so you would need something like (untested, so you'll need to debug it yourself):

```
.globl _start
.extern ExitProcess
_start:
    call main           # call main without any setup.
    push %eax           # push main return code for delivery to OS.
                        # win64 equiv is, I think: mov %eax, %ecx
    call ExitProcess    # And off we go.
```

and then work out how to link with the Windows dll/lib files.

Comment: @Basile: very unlikely, given the `int $80` is a Linux think. The Windows equivalent would have you calling `ExitProcess` with an argument of zero. I'll add that to the answer but it's not definitive since my expertise in that area is limited. The *approach,* however, should work.

Comment: @paxdiablo when I tried your suggestion with the command `gcc -lkernel32 -lgcc -lmsvcrt -nostdlib -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -o main main.c mystart.S`, I got some of the errors I was getting with the `-nodefaultlibs` option. Alot of undefined references: https://pastebin.com/y4v1S3mB

Comment: @TryingMyBest: yes, if you try to *use* stuff that's not in the files you link, you will get undefined references. My approach intentionally had a minimal `main` just so this did not happen. What you need to do is, for each of those undefined references, either modify your code so you don't use it, or link in the files that provide it. I make no suggestion as to whether you'll be able to get below 3K if you use everything you're trying to use, I was only showing how to get your code to compile in the start-up sense.

Comment: @paxdiablo but the libraries those functions belong to is `kernel32.lib`, and I already included that. So I'm wondering why does it say that they're undefined references?

Comment: @TryingMyBest: if you're sure they're *in* the libraries you're linking with then it's probably an ordering issue. Many linkers, when given a library, will use that library to satisfy *currently* unsatisfied symbols. Since the symbols are referenced in `main`, *that's* where they become unsatisfied, so you should move all the `-l<libname>` arguments to *after* `main` and `mystart`.